# Rotate Google Maps API MarkerImage

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rotation, rotatetransform

I have a marker of a rocket on one of my Google Maps apps. Not surprisingly, I need to rotate it depending on where it's headed. How can I do that? Rotating the image with a canvas/VML (like jquery-rotate does) appears to be not an option, because I need to specify a URL as the image source, not an `<img>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best cross browser way would be to create a sprite with the marker at different angles, and vary the Marker's size attribute depending on the angle.

The other non-cross browser way would be to use CSS3 transforms, and you'd probably want to create a custom Overlay in order to do this. Alternatively, draw onto the map with canvas. Though, you won't get a dom element to capture click events.

Comment: You mean varying offset/anchor? I agree, that will probably work smoother than separate images for every frame.

Comment: Yes. Much. Check here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage I'd be interested to see what you come up with. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can make more versions of that image (for the rotations) and use the url of the image you want.

Comment: That's sort of an obvious and crude solution. However, if no other suggestions appear, I think I'll use this one.